# How to configure Visual Studio for TypeScript

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

My Visual Studio 2015 does not support TypeScript. How to install and to take resources for Angular, Bottstrap.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.

Comment: Did you check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html ?